# Неясное поведение атрибута OptionalAttribute

Tags: c#, .net, com

Для начала приведу простой пример кода:

```
int CopyFromBitmap
(
#if UNI
    [In, Optional] Point2U *destPoint,
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object bitmapObject,
    [In, Optional] RectU *srcRect
#else
    [In, Optional] ref Point2U destPoint,
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object bitmapObject,
    [In, Optional] ref RectU srcRect
#endif
);
```

Каким образом необязательный параметр, идет перед обязательным но, при этом ничего не сообщается, ни ошибок, ни предупреждений.

Выходной код выглядит так:

[image: Странное определение]

Как такое вообще возможно?

Comment: А где необязательный параметр? Три параметра, как и в [мсдн](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-id2d1bitmap-copyfrombitmap). Это наверное одино из перегрузок данного метода на C#

Comment: Речь не о самом параметре, а о том как ведет себя атрибут.

Comment: Перезагрузка метода, вероятно там эту структуру создают внутри и кидают оригинальной функции, по этому параметров два в вашем скриншоте. А атрибут говорит о том что значительно может быть null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Магия. В .NET есть два способа задания необязательных параметров:

1. Указывая значение по умолчанию средствами языка, например в C# `void Test(int x, int y, int z=0)`. При этом способе все необязательные параметры должны быть указаны в конце списка аргументов, это проверяется при компиляции метода.
2. Способ с [Optional], который можно применять в любых языках, даже если они не поддерживают синтаксис значения по умолчанию. Значение по умолчанию будет Type.Missing. При данном способе можно указать необязательные аргументы до обязательных. Однако, пропустить эти аргументы можно будет только при использовании именованных аргументов (проверка осуществляется при компиляции вызова метода):

```
void Test([Optional] int x, int y, [Optional]int z)
{
     Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", x, y, z);
} 

Test(2);   // => CS7036 Отсутствует аргумент, соответствующий требуемому формальному параметру "y"
Test(y:2); // => 0 2 0
```

Ничего специфичного для COM Interop на этот раз вроде нет.